# Problems with Virtual Box 5

Tags: virtualbox

I would really appreciate your help. I was running VM box in my Ubuntu 14 but I was facing several issues so I decided to uninstall and install again. I used the Ubuntu software center and after installed I tried to  create my first virtual machine. However i get the following message:

```
where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime
what:  4
VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.`RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing 

/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime
what:  4
VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.*
```

I have run a command to see what version i have and i see the following.

[image]

Please help

Comment: Maybe run `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and see what happens? It'll store its output in a logfile. If you can't figure out what the logfile is saying, please post it. My random guess is that it's a kernel matching problem (I had that when installing on Fedora 24- Virtualbox is very picky about the exact kernel version).

Comment: i run it but it says .. "No such file or directory"

Comment: Well, since both VirtualBox and I are suggesting you run this command, you might want to download it (it should come w/ VirtualBox, but poke around and, as a last resort, google). You might also try upgrading to virtualbox-5.0